# MS Word find capitalised words containing specific characters

Tags: regex, ms-word, diacritics

I want MS Word to find all proper nouns in a text that contain letters with diacritics (specifically: *áéíóöőúüű*). So find *Ómar* and *Omár* but not *Omar*.

I can find proper nouns with no problem using the <[A-ZÁÉÍÓÖŐÚÜŰ]*> pattern but this will only find diacritics in initials (e.g. Ómar) but not in the rest of the word (e.g. Omár).

Could you lend a hand with this?

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend you ask this on Super User or Microsoft Answers as it's basically an end-user, not a programming question. Word has its own FIND/REPLACE that does *not* use RegEx. If regex type searches are needed, then Word has "wildcards".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. In fact, I thought the task would be out of the scope of MS Word wildcards but gave it a last try here. Will try MS fora then. Thanks again!

Comment: The thing with trying here: Stack Overflow expects a certain amount of research / effort by the person asking a question. You may want to read on the site's [help] about how to effectively ask questions here so that people can give helpful and targeted answers :-) If you find you require a certain amount of code that's not offered elsewhere, record what works to a certain point in a macro and include that in your question. Describe exactly what you have, what you expect and how the macro isn't fulfilling the requirement (do NOT simply say "it doesn't work" <g>).

Comment: @LeventeNagy if you still need it I can show you a possible solution after you have updated your question with the research/code you have so far.

Answer (score -1):

This might not be the optimal solution, but I guess this will work:

```
(?:[ÁÉÍÓÖŐÚÜŰ]+[a-záéíóöőúüű]*|[A-Z][a-z]*[áéíóöőúüű][a-záéíóöőúüű]*)
```

Comment: No matches are found in `find Ómar and Omár but not Omar`. MS Word does not allow NFA regular expression. It only supports specific wildcard expressions (that they call regex, but it is not regular language as there is not way to match an empty string).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the hint, I was not aware of that. I guess I will still leave it here, in case it might help someone else not working with MS Word.

Comment: You might probably wondered what `<` and `>` are for in OP regex. Those are word boundaries, `\b` in regex.

Comment: Thanks both of you for the contribution. And yeah, I also regularly bump into these differences between MS wildcards and regexes.

Comment: You could use a *wildcard* Find for [ÁÉÍÓÖŐÚÜŰáéíóöőúüű], which will locate all those characters, but won't find the entire word. A *wildcard* Find for [ÁÉÍÓÖŐÚÜŰáéíóöőúüű]*> will find from the first of those characters to the end of the word, but there's no reliable *wildcard* for finding a whole word containing any of those characters. A macro could be used to extend the found range back to the start of the word, however.